# In what cases does the return value of getInnerSize() become null?

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm trying to scroll to the row found using the setFocusedCell() function of the table.
[setFocusedCell() method](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/7bda3ee5941c1e3a76e9fc13323b324995e9e043/source/class/qx/ui/table/Table.js#L1564C14-L1564C14)

However, the scrolling feature is not working because the return value of getInnerSize() becomes null.
[call getInnerSize()](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/7bda3ee5941c1e3a76e9fc13323b324995e9e043/source/class/qx/ui/table/pane/Scroller.js#L1735)

In what cases does the return value of getInnerSize() become null?

Answer (score 1):

Real sizes of a witdget you can get after it will be added to DOM and rendered. Consider `appear` event to get not null value of `getInnerSize()`. There is another method which you find interesting - `getSizeHint`.